# How to calculate textboxes values only when all textboxes are filled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I make some calculations based on the values of 4 textboxes, however what I want is to calculate this only when the 4 textboxes have values.

Sounds simple, but I can not think a way of running the calc only when the above conditional is true and re-calculated on every keyup.

```
$(window).load(function(){
     $('#quantity, #length, #width, #height, #weight').keyup(function () {
         $('#volumetric_weight').val($('#length').val()*$('#width').val()*$('#height').val()*$('#quantity').val()/5000);
```

Comment: Can include `html` at Question ?

Comment: Just for the record... I suggest you to replace "keyup" with "change" because if the user paste the value, keyup event won't be triggered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `required` attribute , calculate only when each `input` is valid

```js
$(function() {
  var inputs = $("form input"), product = 1;
  inputs.on("input", function() {
    if (document.forms["calculate"].checkValidity()) {
      inputs.each(function(i, el) {
        product *= el.value;
      });
      $("#volumetric_weight").val(product / 5000);
      product = 1;
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<form name="calculate">
  <input type="number" id="quantity" required />
  <input type="number" id="length" required />
  <input type="number" id="width" required />
  <input type="number" id="height" required />
  <input type="number" id="weight" required />
</form>

<input type="text" value="" id="volumetric_weight" />
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/b185Lh80/

Comment: do you an by submitting the form? I dont want to submit it.

Comment: No, `this.checkValidity()` should return `false` if `input` `value` does not have `.length` greater than `0` ; `form` is not required . Can include `html` at Question ?

Comment: Yes I can Include html

Answer (score 1):

You need to check first that the input field has a value (all of them), then execute your code.
In your question you mention 4 textboxes, but in your code you have 5 ;)
Something like this

```
    $(window).load(function(){

         $('#quantity, #length, #width, #height, #weight').keyup(function () {
if(!$('#quantity').val() || !$('#length').val() || !$('#width').val() || !$('#height').val() || !$('#weight').val()) return;

             $('#volumetric_weight').val($('#length').val()*$('#width').val()*$('#height').val()*$('#quantity').val()/5000);
```

Comment: Was thinking the same thing. You may want to do some `!isNaN` for those vals too. Of course all the values will be strings, so you'll need to parseFloat or whatever type of number you need there too.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply test that all values exist before computing:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('#quantity, #length, #width, #height, #weight').change(function () {
    var len = $('#length').val();
        width = $('#width').val();
        height = $('#height').val();
        qty = $('#quantity').val();
    if (!!len && !!width && !!height && !!qty) {
      $('#volumetric_weight').val(len * width * height * qty / 5000);
    }
  });
})
```

Note that I used the recommendation of @Mathew: substitute `change()` to `keyup()` in order to also catch when user pasts.